# Is this a well defined problem in terms of Euclidean Geometry?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, transcendental-numbers, automated-theorem-proving

I am trying to construct an example of a geometric problem, stated in terms of Euclidean Geometry, that is not Machine Provable (or in an equivalent definition Automatically Provable)-i.e no computer can solve it. 

As far as I can tell, the process by which the machine goes about tackling the problem involves transforming it into polynomial expressions, so transcedental numbers seem the obvious choice. So, let's chose a well-known transcedental number, $2^{\sqrt 2}$ (Gelfond–Schneider constant) and state the problem as such:

> Given a line segment $a$, of length $2$, and an isosceles right triangle whose sides are of length $1$, can we construct by ruler and compass a line segment equal to $a$ to the power of $b$, where $b$ is the length of the hypotenuse of the given triangle?

This might seem like a superflous way of coming up with $2^{\sqrt 2}$ but I want to make sure that it makes sense in terms of Euclidean Geometry. That is, someone who, say, has only read The Elements would understand it. 

So, does this seem to do the trick? Is the problem valid as a strictly euclidean geometry problem, and if so, is it automatically solvable?

Comment: If someone has only read the Elements, an irrational exponent is unclear and impossible to interpret.  An integer power and even a rational power, but not an irrational power.  So, no.    Why not simply ask for the length of the hypotenuse?  Because there is no straightforward consistant way to derive/construct the length $2^a$ from the length $a$.  $2^a$ and $a$ are different concepts.  Actually, I don't know how having 2 as a *length* to a power (integer, rational, or other) is supposed to be interpreted.

Comment: What does a segment length to an integer power mean?  I'm not sure I know as I'm not sure I know that lengths=numbers.  But I could be wrong.  If length = number is acceptable, I can accept $a^{n/m} = $ the m-th root of $a^n$ but I can not interpret $a^x$ where $x$ is irrational.  Unless Euclidean Geometry understands cauchy limits?  Does it?  I don't know the answer but those are issues the jump out at me.

Comment: @fleablood Well, powers are used in the Elements, but precisely because ancient Greeks were keen to work with given lengths-in many ways their mathematics are the..geometrization of Algebra-I chose a length that would make sense, would be easily constructible by our ancient geometer-the length of the hypotenuse. So as to avoid symbolic expressions like $a^b$ that create problems.

Comment: The answer to the "can we construct" question is _no._ Even to _ask_ the question, you must introduce things from outside the realm of geometry as Euclid would have understood it--you say "$a$ to the power of $b$" and he says, "$a$ to the _what?_"

Comment: You can't even construct $2^{4/3}$ with ruler and compass, let alone $2^{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the comment David! I am not so sure about this though. Euclid used the term "power" to describe the square of a given length. Can you think of a way to improve this in a matter that would make sense to..Euclid?

Comment: Have you ever seen a copy of Euclid's elements made before the year 1400 CE, or a verbatim excerpt from such a copy, _not_ translated by someone who lived more recently, and were you able to read it? Then you have the advantage over me. If not, I'll retain my opinion that "power" is a modern word introduced as an interpretation of the Elements. The important point, however, is that only rational powers make sense in that context.

Comment: @DavidK Well, knowing Greek and some basic ancient Greek gives me a slight edge I dare say:-) . Euclid used the term "δύναμις" which is almost identical to the modern greek word "δύναμη" and translates exactly as power in english. Again, I am certain that he used it to express the square of a given length. I am actively searching for more examples but it is not easy given the size of his work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37741/discussion-between-david-k-and-mathematicianbymistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs a precise definition of "stated in terms of Euclidean geometry." The axioms given by Euclid are imprecise, and incomplete.

If we make them precise, for example by using the first-order axiomatization by Tarski, we have the result of Tarski that the theory is decidable. This is a consequence of the fact that the first-order theory of real-closed fields is decidable.

If we are much looser and allow the introduction of integers, or rationals (say via commensurability)  then undecidability is a consequence of the undecidability of the first-order theory of integers, or the first-order theory of rationals.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suppose the best definition I can come up with-and I fully understand it's weakness and that this is at the core of the problem-would be for this problem to make sense to someone whose mathematical training involves solely the Elements. (As was the case for many generations..)

Comment: There is no algorithm for determining whether a sentence $\varphi$ made up by using addition, multiplication, and the usual logical symbols is true in the rationals. With a little care, from such a sentence we can construct explicitly a sentence $\varphi'$ of "Euclidean geometry" such that $\varphi$ is true in the rationals if and only if $\varphi'$ is true in the plane, However, we have to use notions that go beyond such concepts as incidence and betweenness. Using commensurability as a basic notion will work, and the concept certainly is in Euclid.

Comment: "..we can construct explicitly a sentence $φ′$ of "Euclidean geometry" such that $φ$ is true in the rationals if and only if $φ′$ is true in the plane" I think this sums up perfectly the strategy I try to pursue here. It is of no mater whether this can be solved within the limits of "Euclidean Geometry", the deduction, or rather the interpretation of the statement $φ'$ to $φ$ and subsequent attempt to resolve it would be the computer's task. Actually I believe your comment supplements your answer in a way that can be considered-at least by me-sufficient for the problem. Thnx again!